# Remove duplicates after $sample

Tags: mongodb

I'm using `$sample` to get some random documents from a collection:

```
db.myCollection.aggregate(
   [ { $sample: { size: 100 } } ]
)
```

Due to the nature of `$sample`, same documents may get retrieved more than once, so my sample of 100 may contain duplicates. How can I remove the duplicates after sampling?

Comment: Do you want "duplicates removed" or do you want "100 unique results"? Because your answers to date won't return the latter. Also state what exactly makes a "duplicate document", because without actually showing that, then nobody can actually tell. The `_id` key is quite obviously "unique" unless of course you are actually adding this to the end of an existing aggregation pipeline.